# Start Ubuntu 18.04 without graphics card

Tags: 18.04, graphics, startup

I set up a Ubuntu Server without any extra packages but openssh-server. Now my goal is to remove the graphics card from the computer because of saving power and preventing heat. The problem is that the server is not starting without a graphics card anymore. I already tried using `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` with

```
Section "Device"  
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"  
    Driver      "dummy"   EndSection  

Section "Monitor"  
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"  
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5  
    VertRefresh 50-70   EndSection  

Section "Screen"   
    Identifier  "Default Screen"  
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"  
    Device      "Configured Video Device"  
    DefaultDepth 24  
    SubSection "Display"  
    Depth 24  
    Modes "1024x800"  
    EndSubSection
```

written to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it had no effect.

EDIT: I can not see where the startup is interrupted because I can not hotplug the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server does not even install X. How did you end up with it?

I run Ubuntu Server on thousands of headless machines, none have a video card, and they all run fine. And none have X installed, of course.

Comment: I do not know. I have downloaded the Server CD from the official website and made a bootable USB-Stick. During installation I had a video card and display connected but I did not install X...

Comment: Isn’t it allowed to use a video card during installation? Or do I need to set up Ubuntu Server with something like kickstart?

Comment: yes, you can have a video card and then take it out. But if you have not installed X, then you cannot possibly be getting an error message from X!

Comment: But which other error could be called when removing the video card?